# Group Data Within Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping, sql-server-2014

I wrote this query and the results are not being grouped. They are appearing as such:

```
Facility | Posting Month | Account Type | Amount
-------------------------------------------------
Name     | July          | Debit Adj.   | 100
Name     | July          | Credit Adj.  | -200
Name     | July          | Debit Adj.   | 150
Name     | July          | Credit Adj.  | -150
-------------------------------------------------
```

The results I am trying to get is the Posting month to appear once for the Debit Adj. and Credit Adj. type and the respective total amounts. Total of $250 for Debits and -$350 for credits. Thanks for the help!

```
SELECT pw.Facility, DATENAME(mm, pw.[Posting Date]) AS [Posting Month],
     lc.[Gl Account Type], sum(pw.[Tx Amt]) AS Amount
FROM DBO.PaymentWOLedger AS pw
    JOIN DBO.LedgerCodeTable AS lc
      ON lc.[Description] = pw.[Tx Desc]
WHERE lc.[Gl Account Type] = 'Credit Adjustment (Write Off)' OR 
      lc.[GlAccount Type] = 'Debit Adjustment (CWO)'
GROUP BY pw.[Posting Date], pw.Facility, lc.[Gl Account Type]
ORDER BY pw.Facility, pw.[Posting Date]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Month` instead of `Date` in `Group by` & `Order by`

```
GROUP BY DATENAME(mm, pw.[Posting Date]), pw.Facility, lc.[Gl Account Type]
ORDER BY pw.Facility, DATENAME(mm, pw.[Posting Date])
```

currently the data is grouped on each `date` since you have used `pw.[Posting Date]` in `Group by` which has `date/month/year` part in it.

Comment: Awesome! It makes sense now. Thank you for the help!